# Retrieve value from toolStripComboBox

Tags: c#, toolstripcombobox

I have created a `toolStripComboBox` and retrieve all the item list selection from the database something like this:

```
private void toolStripComboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.ValueMember = "month";
        toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = dbConnect.selectMonth(); //get all month from the database
    }
```

The comboBox then display all month from database.

Later then I'm trying to fetch the selection from the comboBox using `selectedItem` somthing like this:

```
string monthSelect = toolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

However I get the value `monthSelect = "System.Data.DataRowView"`

Any idea how to get the value instead of `System.Data.DataRowView`?

Answer (score 6):

Got a solution for this. When using Datasource for toolStripComboBox like :

```
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.ValueMember = "valueMember";  
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = datasource();  //retrieve value from database into comboBox list
```

toolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem will only return the customized view of a DataRow. In order to get the value of the current selection need to use :

```
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```